# Is there a way to 'clean out' physical memory (RAM) that is tied up on my Centos/Apache webserver?

Tags: memory, apache-http-server, centos, javascript

I am developing something that requires Server-side javascript, and as such am using PhatomJS to run the JS.

It uses up about a 1GB of physical memory when all is well, but if I screw up some javascript it seems to really soak up the memory, spiking to 3.5GB total usage - and crashing phantomJS.

PhantomJS restarts ok but I notice that the RAM usage remains up at 3.5GB, and I just have to wait about 15 minutes for it to come 'back down'.

Is it being assigned to the programme for a certain ammount of time? Is there a way I can reduce this or clean out what's in the physical memory currently to free it up?

Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-clear-memory-cache-on-linux-servers/

Comment: [Are you sure it's an issue?](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) Is the machine actually running any slower?

Comment: Type `$ free -m` to see your memory. If you have a lot of it Free, or in buffer/cache you are okay. If it's in Swap, then it's really eating up the memory.

Comment: @JREAM thanks for the advice - checked free -m and there was indeed much more listed free than according to my virtualmin dashboard. Many thanks

Comment: @Gideon Those things seem to never display correctly with many Hosts they only check the Physical Ram Free that has not yet been used, and that's not true. Glad it helped!